# address function within countif function in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to use the countif function to count the number of unique values in a list

Something like this worked fine

```
=SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF(D27:H27,D27:H27))
```

but when I try to alter the array which I check by doing this

```
=SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF($D27：ADDRESS(ROW($D27),COLUMN($D27)+VRES-1),$D27:ADDRESS(ROW($D27),COLUMN($D27)+VRES-1)))
```

where vres is another cell with a constant.

excel tell me there is a problem with the formula but I can figure out where it is.
The address function works by itself in its own cell, but doesn't seem to work in the countif function

Comment: 1. if you use office 365, you could experiment with UNIQUE formula
2. if you're altering the part of the address as above, you should wrap that part in INDIRECT formula INDIRECT(COUNTIF("$D27:"&ADDRESS(ROW($D27),COLUMN($D27)+VRES-1)) something like that

Comment: What is your excel version?

Comment: I use office 2016 so that is currently not an option for me.
When you mention wrapping the part of the address I'm trying to alter in an INDIRECT formula, do you mean the part with
ADDRESS(ROW($D27),COLUMN($D27)+VRES-1)
or just
COLUMN($D27)+VRES-1

Comment: Avoid the volatile `INDIRECT` and `ADDRESS` functions. `=SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF(D27:INDEX(D27:XFD27,VRES),D27:INDEX(D27:XFD27,VRES)))`

Comment: Don't do it with countif - Frequency is better https://exceljet.net/formula/count-unique-text-values-in-a-range